# What is the equivalent code of the CTRL+C task killing on windows?

Tags: java, cmd, taskkill

On **Windows 7**, I have a Java Application, which can start other JAR-s (which are running in background).

In this Application, I have a button, which shoul **represent the CTRL+C command** for every other started (and still running) JAR-s.
I have found this code, which should **kill the task by PID** (6272):

```
taskkill /F /PID 6272
```

But if I run this code on a command propmt, a lot of times it is just waiting, and than return false, so it cannot kill the program. Sometimes it can kill, sometimes it cannot.

I would need a command, which is similar to CTRL+C, because if you hit this CTRL+C, the actual process will end **immediately**, without waiting!

Could anyone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: you need java code or command line, and how you are launching jars. Is it by `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec`

Comment: I am using this code right now in my java app: **Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID 6272");**

But I need a command, which I can use in this code, and also in CMD by myself

Comment: How you launch the java process????

Comment: **Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java -Xmx100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -jar myapp.jar"); process.waitFor();** and this waitFor method usually return 128 (0 is the return, if i could kill the task)

Comment: Have tried adding `/T` option?

Comment: what is the /T option?

Comment: @victorio /T option Specifies to terminate all child processes along with the parent process. More info at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491009.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why you need the command to fire from Java when you have the hold of `Process` object by which you launch a jar, you can simply use `destroy();` to kill the process you have launched.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "bla bla bla");      
p.destroy();
```

And if you really need to do it manually from command prompt then you have to find the process id and kill it by using the command you have already mentioned, you can read more here [kill process command line windows 7](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/29463-kill-processes-using-command-prompt-windows-7-8-a.html) and [Microsoft Taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491009.aspx)